# Which Cassandra Python driver works with aiohttp?

Tags: python, cassandra, aiohttp, cassandra-driver

The question is which Cassandra Python driver is better to use with aiohttp web framework.

Currently, there are two possible candidates:

1. [cassandra-driver](https://github.com/datastax/python-driver) by DataStax
2. [aiocassandra](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiocassandra)

The thing is, cassandra-driver seems to be more popular and has more support. But on the other side it does not support asyncio (experimental unstable implementation), while asyncio is critical for running aiohttp web server.

aiocassandra is not as popular, and maintanance+support is questionable.

So, does aiocassandra perform way better than cassandra-driver, and which should we choose in terms of uptime and performance and support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cassandra-driver` is used in the project (cqlsh) and the tests for cassandra are written using it (dtests) so will always be maintained, well tested and up to date with all versions of Cassandra.

aiocassandra is a wrapper around cassandra-driver so its performance probably wont be any different.

Answer (score 1):

[aiocassandra](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiocassandra) is now not an option.

The project on Github has been archived since 2020:
https://github.com/aio-libs/aiocassandra/issues/122

[aiocqlengine](https://github.com/CharAct3/aiocqlengine) is another option.

It is basically a wrapper around Datastax's Cassandra Python driver's `cassandra.cqlengine.model`'s.
But it has async/await support:

> ```py
> import asyncio
> import uuid import os
>
> from aiocqlengine.models import AioModel
> from aiocqlengine.query import AioBatchQuery
> from aiocqlengine.session import aiosession_for_cqlengine 
> from cassandra.cluster import Cluster 
> from cassandra.cqlengine import columns, connection, management
>
>
> class User(AioModel):
>     user_id = columns.UUID(primary_key=True)
>     username = columns.Text()
>
> async def run_aiocqlengine_example():
>     ...
>     # Model.objects.all() and Model.all() in async way:
>     print(list(await User.async_all()))
>     print(list(await User.objects.filter(user_id=user_id).async_all()))
>
>     # Model.object.update() in async way:
>     await User.objects(user_id=user_id).async_update(username='updated-user1')
>
>     # Model.objects.get() and Model.get() in async way:
>     user = await User.objects.async_get(user_id=user_id)
>     await User.async_get(user_id=user_id)
>     print(user, user.username)
>
>     # Model.save() in async way:
>     user.username = 'saved-user1'
>     await user.async_save()
>
>     # Model.delete() in async way:
>     await user.async_delete()
>     ...
> ```

It seems to [still be maintained](https://github.com/CharAct3/aiocqlengine/issues/7).